# npm command not working after installing nodejs in windows10?

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-10

[image: i can find npm.cmd][image: command prompt pic][image]i have installed nodejs from nodejs website.
when i typed

```
node -v
```

It gives me the version as

```
  6.11.2
```

But when i type

npm -v
 it doesnt gives me any results.
I have done reinstalling nodejs several times.

my installation path is

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs
```

any help?

[image: this is my git bash command prompt where you can see npm is not giving any result]
[image: my environment variable after installing nodejs is that anything wrong?]

Comment: I think it should be `C:\Program Files\nodejs\bin`. Try adding `\bin`

Comment: /bin to be added in environment varable?

Comment: added , same response as before.

Comment: Uninstall npm, then re-install it.

Comment: i have done reinstalling nodejs several times...
how to reinstall npm alone?

Comment: Did you uninstall completely before reinstall?

Comment: in the control panel i did unintalling .. then in appdata/remote i have removed npm folder.what else to be done?

Comment: What exactly happens when you type `npm -v`?  Do you get an error?  An empty prompt?  The shell hangs?

Comment: an empty prompt. No results it stands where it is.

Comment: You mean it looks like something runs and it returns back to the command prompt, but nothing outputs or it looks like something is still running waiting for it to finish?  And, are you executing NPM from a Command Prompt?

Comment: FYI, you can type `which npm.*` at a command prompt in windows 10 to see what is found on your path that matches that.  It's possible you have a bogus npm.exe or npm.cmd that needs to be manually cleaned up.

Comment: on typing which npm.* i am getting results as no npm in * and a larger path.

Comment: @jfriend00 i have updated my result on typing which npm.* in my question check it.

Comment: i am using gitbash not command prompt.. but in command prompt also same results.

Comment: I don't know if a bash shell can run NPM.  On my computer, NPM is run from NPM.CMD which is a window shell script.

Comment: @jfriend00 oki i have updated using command prompt.check it.

Comment: Where is npm.cmd on your computer?  You can go to the top of a drive and do `dir /s npm.*` and see what it finds on that drive.  It appears that it is not in your path.  I have `npm.cmd` in the same directory as node.exe, put there by the node installer.  Though I'm baffled why running npm doesn't show an error if it isn't being found.  You need to figure out what is running when you type npm at the command prompt.  If you find the right `npm.cmd`, you can try running it directly by specifying a path in front of it to see if it works appropriately.

Comment: on searching for dir /s npm.* i my whole pc it gives me no matches found .

Comment: Go to the directory where node.exe is installed and do a `dir` and share what you see.

Comment: i can find npm.cmd i have updated check.

Comment: What happens when you go to that directory and type `npm -v`?

Comment: same thing happening no response.

Answer (score 2):

Run command `where npm` in node.js cmd, you will get path where it referring.

Remove npm folder from `C:\Users\dname\AppData\Roaming\npm`

Answer (score -1):

npm --version is the windows command line prompt

Comment: All these work just fine for me on Windows 10: `npm -v`, `npm -version` and `npm --version` with NPM v3.10.8.  So, I don't think what you are proposing is necessarily required.

Comment: i  am unable to install any npm package and also npm --version doesnt give me any result.

Comment: do you have a package.json file? if not you should run npm init in the command line to create the file; then npm install in the root of your application