# I installed an older version of nodejs/npm but npm does not work

Tags: node.js, npm

Similar to - [npm command not working after installing nodejs in windows10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45747331/npm-command-not-working-after-installing-nodejs-in-windows10)

Situation:

1. I installed v5.12.0-x64.msi on Windows 10.
2. No npm commands will work.

Facts:

- npm works on my personal computer but not my work computer. Both are on the same network. Both dont have nvm.
- Location of npm has been added to Environment Variables.
- No VPN is in use.
- nvm is not installed.
- `npm -v` displays no output.
- Uninstalling and Reinstalling Nodejs does not fix the problem
- System Restart does not fix the problem
- Node v6.0 has the same issue with `npm` not working
- Node v16.0 does not have the issue
- Command Prompt is in admin mode

Question:

- Any suggestions for potential approaches would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi did you try to restart Windows 10? This fixes for me usually Path issues on Windows, however I am not sure if the issue you are having is related to the Path issue I usually have.

Comment: I got the same problem like you, I installed the old Node version 5.0, 5.12 or 6. I can see it was installed successfully and run command "node --version" to see its version. But when I run command "npm --version" it show an empty line. I even did restart my PC.